# How do I make a text box in a form not visible until after I click compute in C#?

Tags: c#, text, textbox, label

So in the beginning, the user has to input data but in the form. It has textboxes and labels where the answers to the calculations go. I have it so that when it clicks, it computes certain labels and textboxes show up and when the user clicks reset they disappear using:

```
txtTaxesPaid.Visible = true;

txtTaxesPaid.Visible = false;
```

My problem is that in the beginning the ones that are not visible. When I click reset they show up. How do I make them not visible in the very beginning?

Comment: Set them to Visible=False in the designer, or in the Form_Load handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: (shortest and most straight forward)
In VS designer of your form - locate those controls and set the visible property to false.

Option 2:
In your form_load event you can set the initial state of your controls.

Option 3:
You can force to invoke the method of the button which already contain the reset commands from your form_load event.

Option 4: (I think is the preferable choice)
- Create a method for reset..
- call the method from form_load or from your "reset" button or anywhere else you want.

```
private void ResetControls()
{
   txtMyControl.Visible=false;
   //here comes more logic for what to do upon reset.
}

private void form_load(...
{
  ResetControls();
}

private void btnReset_Click(...
{
  ResetControls();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set Textboxes `Visible` property from `Properties` window in the designer.Or you can do it in `Form Load` event programatically:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtTaxesPaid.Visible = false;
}
```

If you don't see Form Load method just double click your Form in the designer and you will see, or find `Load` event from `Properties > Events` window.